# Basic Snackbar Example doesn't show on Material Design Components for Web

Tags: snackbar, mdc-components

The basic example of snackbar for Material Design Components for Web doesn't work. It produces the error:

````
```
TypeError: snackbar.show is not a function
```
````

I have tried using jQuery to make sure the DOM loaded properly. I have tried changing back and forth the javascript initialisation methods, but none seems to work.

You can find the code here: https://jsbin.com/mejefeq/edit?html,console,output

I have read the docs over and overs again, but none of it mentioned anything about this. Since this MDC for Web is not at all popular, I have nowhere left to go for help.

Comment: Have you tried running snackbar.open() ? That will display the DOM text content in the Snackbar body. If you want to change that use snackbar.labelText('New text'). More on that [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-snackbar)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah that was a breaking change in the [0.43.0 update](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0430-2019-01-07). The new way of showing the snackbar is by using

```
snackbar.open();
```

This however will just open the snackbar. If you want to change the text in the snackbar you can use:

```
snackbar.labelText = 'Your new text';
```

So together you can use them:

```
snackbar.labelText = 'Your new text';
snackbar.open();
```

You can check out more of the documentation [here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/snackbars/), with the current javascript properties and events [here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/snackbars/#javascript-api)